# Extending animation clip issue

Tags: animation

How do I extend a short animated walking motion in the Dope Sheet section ? I tried to copy paste the motion key points but the pasted portion returns character from the starting locale point (understandably) ... which would be an additional question .. how to adjust so that it doesn't bring character to starting point.
Here is a clip of what I am trying to explain: (https://streamable.com/0525vz)

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: I got the animation portion of the model from the Mixamo website and created the model using MakeHuman software. Then imported them into Blender. Here is the download link of the Blender file:   (https://www.mediafire.com/file/43r1oafh6w0nelg/Walking+Test.blend/file)

Comment: When I encountered this, I used the graph editor to move the frames up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of animation (long distance walk) you could use a walk cycle and make the armature follow a curve, but, as ZargulTheWizard says, it is pretty easy to fix in the *Graph Editor*:

- First delete the 3 last keyframes (which are identical), select the whole series of keyframes, duplicate them whith <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, move them on the right and keep them selected:

[image]

- Switch to *Graph Editor* with shortcut <kbd>Ctrlt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, unfold the *Armature*'s tracks on the left, select the track called *Z Location (mixamorig.Hips)* which is the root bone, and make it the only one visible with a <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>:

[image]

- Now move up the handles until it fits with the beginning of the curve (keep pressing <kbd>Shiftt</kbd> if you want to move more precisely). Now the character will continue its walk as it should:

[image]

Comment: I didn't see the Armature tracks in graph editor. First screenshot attached is the duplication process and then the second screenshot is what I see in graph editor ... not armature tracks seen. (https://i2.paste.pics/32726c637320fda3d0bb5748b1c1fc07.png)  https://i2.paste.pics/29f10548c772685bf6706121fdbd4db6.png

Comment: it looks like you've unselected the armature, select the armature again

Comment: Here is a video clip of the selection of the armatures yet it still doesn't show the armature tracks in the graph editor. (https://streamable.com/4f2iv2)

Comment: make the armature visible in the Outliner and select it in the 3D view

Comment: Ok I made it visible ( I missed that ). It runs fine now. But after duplicating that portion to extend the walk, I decided to add another duplicate to further extend the walk but that last 'addition' sort of disabled the animation but the model was still moving. I thought intuitively I would simply add as many duplicates of that walking animation to extend the walk a long as I want. Anyway to fix this ?  Here is the video screenshot of what I am talking about: (https://streamable.com/87l3sq)

Comment: select and duplicate the keyframes in the dopesheet, not in the graph editor, otherwise you're just moving the armature keyframes, and not the bones keyframes, maybe it's the problem here? (and make sure that the tracks are selectable in the dope sheet)

Comment: Yep that worked. Thanks for the help. Cheers.